# Hypergraph Colorability

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, hypergraphs

I'm interested in hypergraphs for which there are known (nontrivial) lower bounds on the chromatic number. If someone could point me to existing literature (survey papers etc) on this topic that would be great.

Comment: This is not exactly what you ask for, but you may find it relevant anyway: http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/rraj/Courses/7880/F09/Lectures/GeneralLLL_Apps.pdf. The hypergraph coloring section discusses (perhaps the first known) conditions under which a hypergraph is 2-colorable.

Comment: Do you have a particular application in mind, or do the hypergraphs you are interested in have any notable features?

Comment: I'm mostly interested in regular hypergraphs that have edges of large (non-constant in $n$) size.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any good overview references for hypergraph colouring.  However, Voloshin wrote a nice book on colouring *mixed* hypergraphs, which generalize the usual colouring condition.

In addition to requiring that at least two vertices in every edge receive Different colours (as in the usual setup), in a mixed hypergraph some edges may be required to have at least two vertices that both receive a Common colour.  One can just assume that there are no Common restrictions, so this is a generalization.

There are then several nice classes of mixed hypergraphs for which one can give non-trivial bounds on the chromatic number.  These include pseudo-chordal and $C$-perfect mixed hypergraphs.  Voloshin also provides over two hundred references, many of them relating to the classical setting.

- Vitaly I. Voloshin, Coloring Mixed Hypergraphs: Theory, Algorithms and Applications.  AMS, 2002.  ISBN 0-8218-2812-6.